# CSS 3 column fluid layout issues, 3rd column too wide

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to implement a 3 column fluid layout by following http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/ (left 300px fixed, center fluid, right 300px fixed) and for some reason the 3rd column is blowing out the right side of the layout.

Here's what I want vs what I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFVVP.png

Am testing it on Linux Chrome and FF - both latest stable versions.

My css is:

```
#home {
    min-width:900px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #565656;
}

/* Main Page Divisions */

#page-top {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ffffffff;
}

#page-middle {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #6AC0EB;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 300px;   /* LC width */
    padding-right: 300px;  /* RC width */
}

#page-middle .column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#page-bottom {
    clear:both;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    overflow:scroll;
}

/* Middle Page Divisions */

#page-middle-centre {
    width:60%;
}

#page-middle-left {
    width: 300px;          /* LC width */
    right: 300px;          /* LC width */
    margin-left: -60%;
}
#page-middle-right {
    width: 300px;          /* RC width */
    margin-right:-300px;  /* RC width */
    background: #FDE95E;
}

/* Bottom Page Divisions */

#page-bottom-left {
    width: 49%; 
    float:left;
    text-align: right;
}

#page-bottom-right {
    width: 49%; 
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Quicksand";
    font-size: 130%;
}

h1#title-block {
    font-family: "Quicksand";
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
}
```

And my HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="home">


    <div id="page-top">
    This is the header  
  </div>


    <div id="page-middle">

    <div id="page-middle-centre" class="column">
        middle section middle section middle section middle section middle section middle section middle section middle section  
    </div>      

    <div id="page-middle-left" class="column">
          <h1 id="title-block">Title Block</h1>
          <p id="quicksand">Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4</p>
    </div>

    <div id="page-middle-right" class="column">
      Right section Right section Right section Right section Right section Right section Right section Right section 
    </div>  
  </div>

    <div id="page-bottom">
    This is the footer
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the width:100% on the page-middle element was causing it...

```
#page-middle {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #6AC0EB;
    float:left;
    width:100%;   <----------------
    padding-left: 300px;   /* LC width */
    padding-right: 300px;  /* RC width */
}
```

Once it was removed, everything aligned. Not quite sure I understand the logic behind this, but at least it's fixed.

Comment: reason here: w3c box model. In this model, actual width = padding + content width + border width, so actual width in #page-middle = 100% of parent width + padding-left + padding right [reference](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

In your html your column divs are in the order of:

1. Left column
2. Center column
3. Right column

The example that you are using on the alistapart site has its columns in the order of:

1. Center column
2. Left column
3. Right column

Switch these around and it might work properly.
Good Luck!

Comment: I actually had that and copied the incorrect version - I've edited my code to reflect. Any other ideas?? This is driving me insane!